# Copy modify and store objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angularjs project that with an array of objects. Supporting evergreen browsers only.

**Factory**

```
var _data = [];
var _myObject = {};
var _objectsModified = [];

function loadData(){
    $http.get("data.json").success(function(response){
        _data = response.data;//[{id: 1, title: "foo"},{id: 2, title: "bar"}]
        _data.forEach(function(e,i){ 
            _myObject[e.id] = i;
        });
    });
}

function getData(){
    return _data;
}

function getObjectById(id){
    return _data[_myObject[id]];
}

function storeObjectById(object){
    _data[_myObject[object.id]] = object;
    _objectsModified.push(object);
}

function saveModifications(){
    $http.put("save_endpoint", _objectsModified).success(function(response){
        if(response.success) _objectsModified = [];
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
var objectCopy = angular.copy(getObjectById(1));
// user makes changes to the object
// store object
storeObjectById(objectCopy);
```

The Controller is creating an angular copy of an object, editing it then putting it back into the array.

Is this an efficient way to do this?

---

**Edits**

1. Updated the question to include an [angular.extend()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) example.
2. Created a reference in Factory to the requested edit object.
3. Used angular.extend() passing in the reference and modified object.

**Factory**

```
var _data = [];
var _objectsModified = [];
var _editObjectRef = {};

function loadData(){
    $http.get("data.json").success(function(response){
        _data = response.data;//[{id: 1, title: "foo"},{id: 2, title: "bar"}]
    });
}

function getData(){
    return _data;
}

function getCopyOfObject(object){
    _editObjectRef = object;
    return angular.copy(_editObjectRef);
}

function storeModifiedObject(object){
    angular.extend(_editObjectRef, object);
    _objectsModified.push(object);
}

function saveModifications(){
    $http.put("save_endpoint", _objectsModified).success(function(response){
        if(response.success) _objectsModified = [];
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.data = Factory.loadData();
$scope.editObject = function(object){
    $scope.editObjectCopy = Factory.getCopyOfObject(object);
}
$scope.storeModifiedObject = function(object){
    Factory.storeModifiedObject(object);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-repeat="object in data" ng-click="editObject(object)">{{object.title}}</a>
```

Comment: can use `angular.extend()` to merge updates from edited object into original. Easier than replacing when in arrays and doesn't break object references since original object is only being modified

Comment: Thank you charlietfl, I will experiment with [angular.extend()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) and [angular.merge()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

Is there an easier way to get and set modified objects, can this be done with Angular without the need for another array of object references?

Comment: What I do is store a reference to object that is being copied to edit ... `var selectedItem=item` and make copy `$scope.editItem = angular.copy(selectedItem)` Then when you are done editing ... `angular.extend(selectedItem, $scope.editItem)` Just need to hoist `var` so it is in scope in several different functions or store in a service. The next time you use that variable you break the reference to the previous one so it remains unaffected by subsequent object edits